# Selenium launches new browser window then throws UnreachableBrowserException

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I am trying to setup a new Selenium project, and can not make thinks work correctly. My environment:

```
OSX      : 10.12.4
Java     : 1.8.0_121
Selenium : 3.4.0
Gecko    : 0.16.1      ( located at /opt/garbage/geckodriver and on path )
Firefox  : 53.0.3
```

Java Code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/opt/garbage/geckodriver");
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "/opt/garbage/geckodriver");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();  <--

driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

In this example, line 4 will open a new Firefox Browser window, but several seconds later throws the following stack:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'myhostname.corp', ip: '10.99.99.99', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.4', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:658)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:104)
    at com.example.TestClass.testMethod(TestClass.java:19)
```

And StdErr from the failed run:

```
2017-06-05 12:24:08.483 firefox-bin[35514:5688975] IMKInputSession presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:completionHandler: : [self textInputContext]=0x12cd37a00 *NO* NSRemoteViewController to client, NSError=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection from pid 0" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection from pid 0}, com.apple.inputmethod.EmojiFunctionRowItem
2017-06-05 12:24:08.891 firefox-bin[35514:5688975] IMKInputSession presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:completionHandler: : [self textInputContext]=0x12cd37a00 *NO* NSRemoteViewController to client, NSError=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection from pid 0" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection from pid 0}, com.apple.inputmethod.EmojiFunctionRowItem
2017-06-05 12:24:09.248 plugin-container[35516:5689303] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x983b, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2017-06-05 12:24:09.248 plugin-container[35516:5689303] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x9b03, name = 'com.apple.CFPasteboardClient'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
```

What could I have misconfigured?

*edit*

I have also tried using the following capabilities - without change

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new FirefoxOptions()//
        .setProfile(new FirefoxProfile())//
        .addTo(DesiredCapabilities.firefox());

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver( caps );  <--
```

Comment: Update the browser's driver to latest. like Cromer Cromedriver/ IEdriver

Comment: `0.16.1` does appear to be the latest driver. [source](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

Comment: this issue tracker may help : https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/opt/garbage/geckodriver.exe");
`WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`  <--
 driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

My Config:

Selenium:3.4.0

Gecko:0.16.1
Firefox:53.0.3

Comment: Removing this one property has no change.